# Copy selected <li> to another <ul> with js

Tags: javascript, html

```
function addSelected(clicked_id) {
  // alert(clicked_id);
  const ul = document.getElementById("sortable2");
  const listItems = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  //   const ul2 = document.getElementById('slottable1');

  // Loop through the NodeList object.
  for (let i = 0; i <= listItems.length - 1; i++) {
    if (listItems[i].className == "selectedli") console.log(listItems[i]);

    //need to copy these <li> tags in another <ul> list
  }
}

<ul id="slottable">
//need to copy selected <li> here and also remove class from those selected <li> before adding here
</ul>
```

output of the console:

```
<li id="pc_103" class="selectedli">B73</li>
<li id="pc_104" class="selectedli">B74</li>
```

I have successfully printed li which I want to copy to another ul in console logs but not able to find the right code to copy them to my another ul. I also need to remove the class 'selectedli' from the li before adding it to the ul 'slottable'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done by creating dynamic tag inside `slottable`.

See below example:

```js
const getChild = document.getElementById("sortable2").children;

function addSelected() {
    let createUl = document.createElement("ul");
    createUl.id = "slottable";
    document.getElementById("tagBox").appendChild(createUl);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < getChild.length; i++) {
        if (getChild[i].className == "selectedli")
        {
            var createLi = document.createElement("li");
            createLi.id = getChild[i].id
            createLi.classList.add(getChild[i].classList);
            createLi.innerHTML = getChild[i].textContent;
        
            createUl.appendChild(createLi);
            console.log(getChild[i]);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("sortable2").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
ul
{
   list-style: none;
}

#sortable2
{
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
    width: 30px;
}
    
#slottable
{
    padding: 10px;
    background: green;
    width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="tagBox">

    </div>
    
    <ul id="sortable2">
       <li id="pc_103" class="selectedli">B73</li>
        <li id="pc_104" class="selectedli">B74</li> 
    </ul>
    
    <input type="button" onclick="addSelected()" value="submit">
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the ans it worked. Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70403155/the-variable-outside-if-else-is-not-accessible-in-for-loop

Comment: Basically what I want to achieve is dynamically selecting "pickNewUl" in if else but then its not working in for loop

Comment: If you can check what i am doing wrong in creating if else

Comment: checking........

Comment: Check my modified answer @Jack

Comment: This will give fixed slottable but mine will be not fixed and I need to choose  one between slottable1-10 depending upon which button is clicked

Comment: if(clicked_id == "add1")
                        {
                        //    alert(clicked_id);
                          const pickNewUl = document.getElementById("slottable1");
                        }
                        else if(clicked_id == "add2")
                        {
                            const pickNewUl = document.getElementById("slottable2");
                        }

Comment: For eg above if else loop, need to choose one like this.

Comment: i think data is coming from database?

Comment: if(clicked_id == "add1")
                        {
                        //    alert(clicked_id);
                          var pickNewUlsl = "slottable1";
                        }
                        else if(clicked_id == "add2")
                        {
                            var pickNewUlsl = "slottable2";
                        }
                       
                      const pickNewUl = document.getElementById(pickNewUlsl);

Comment: Above solves my issue. Its working now. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

The `appendChild()` method should work.

Like this:

```js
sortable2.appendChild(selectedli)
```

To remove classes, use `selectedli.classList.remove(selectedli)`

Answer (score 0):

You looking for something like that?
It copied from one ul to the new ul and removes the class.

`classList.remove` and `appendChild`:

```
  lis.map((el) => {    
    el.classList.remove('selectedli');
    el.innerText += ' (copied and without classs slectedli)'
    ul2.appendChild(el)
  })
```

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('transfer');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // copy from slottable to sortable2
  const ul = document.getElementById("slottable").children;
  const ul2 = document.getElementById("sortable2");    
  let lis = Object.values(ul);
  
  lis.map((el) => {    
    el.classList.remove('selectedli');
    el.innerText += ' (copied and without classs slectedli)'
    ul2.appendChild(el)
  })  
  ul.innerHTML = '';  
});
```

```css
.green {
  background: green;
}

.gray {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul id="slottable" class="gray">
  <li id="pc_103" class="selectedli">B73</li>
  <li id="pc_104" class="selectedli">B74</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="green"></ul>

<button id="transfer">click </button>
```